# Custom SwiftUI layout that specifies both width and height

Tags: swiftui

I have custom Layouts which provide a relative HStack or VStack (based on code from Paul Hudson's Pro SwiftUI book).  However, I need my subviews to have frames that are relative to the parent view size in both directions.  So if the height is 50% of the parent's height, the width should be 50% of the parent's width.  I can't get this to work;  specifying fixed sizes for both height and width to the call to ProposedViewSize results in unexpected and unexplainable (by me, anyway) results.

I've searched for other custom layout examples and it seems like all of them specify either width or height and allow the other dimension to be flexible, which generally means that the subviews are hugging their content.  Am I trying to do something that SwiftUI doesn't support?  If not, can someone please explain or point me to an example?  Thanks in advance!

Update:

There were a couple of requests for code, so here you go. You can paste this into a playground.

RelativeVStack is a vertical version of RelativeHStack, which is from Paul Hudson's Pro SwiftUI book. I got it working vertically and then tried to get it to work in both directions, which is when the trouble started.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
      RelativeVStack() {
        Spacer()
          .layoutPriority(25)
          .border(.pink)
        LayoutStruct()
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
          .layoutPriority(50)
        Spacer()
          .layoutPriority(25)
          .border(.yellow)
      }
      .border(.red)
    }
  }
}

struct LayoutStruct: View {

  var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
      RelativeVStack() {
        Spacer()
          .layoutPriority(25)
          .border(.pink)
        ImageStruct()
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
          .layoutPriority(30)
        TextStruct()
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
          .layoutPriority(20)
        Spacer()
          .layoutPriority(25)
          .border(.yellow)
      }
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
      .border(.purple)
    }
  }
}

struct ImageStruct: View {

  var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "globe")
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
      .imageScale(.large)
      .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
      .border(.green)
  }
}

struct TextStruct: View {

  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, world!")
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
      .border(.blue)
  }
}

struct RelativeVStack: Layout {
  var spacing = 0.0

  func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout Void) -> CGSize {
    let initialHeight = proposal.replacingUnspecifiedDimensions().height
    let initialWidth = proposal.replacingUnspecifiedDimensions().width
    let viewFrames = frames(for: subviews, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: initialWidth, height: initialHeight))
    let width = viewFrames.max { $0.maxX < $1.maxX } ?? .zero
    let height = viewFrames.max { $0.maxY < $1.maxY } ?? .zero
    return CGSize(width: width.maxX, height: height.maxY)
  }

  func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout Void) {
    let viewFrames = frames(for: subviews, in: bounds)

    for index in subviews.indices {
      let frame = viewFrames[index]
      let position = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX - (frame.minX / 2), y: bounds.minY + frame.minY)
      let proposal = ProposedViewSize(frame.size)
      subviews[index].place(at: position, anchor: .top, proposal: proposal)
    }
  }

  func frames(for subviews: Subviews, in bounds: CGRect) -> [CGRect] {
    let totalSpacing = spacing * Double(subviews.count - 1)
    let availableHeight = bounds.height - totalSpacing
    let availableWidth = bounds.width
    let totalPriorities = subviews.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.priority }

    var viewFrames = [CGRect]()
    var y = 0.0

    for subview in subviews {
      let subviewHeight = availableHeight * subview.priority / totalPriorities
      let subviewWidth = availableWidth * subview.priority / totalPriorities
// passing nil for width gives correct result vertically, but content hugging horizontally
//      let proposal = ProposedViewSize(width: nil, height: subviewHeight)
      let proposal = ProposedViewSize(width: subviewWidth, height: subviewHeight)
      let size = subview.sizeThatFits(proposal)
      let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
      viewFrames.append(frame)
      y += size.height + spacing
    }

    return viewFrames
  }
}
```

This is what it looks like when I only set height:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/gaqksy5rg8ijbh3nmassd/Simulator-Screenshot-iPhone-15-Pro-2023-12-15-at-12.04.23.jpeg?rlkey=6sqfcj7uybk8ppau4i0uubpyb&dl=0

And this is what it looks like when I try to set width as well:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/i1eqxngco8wzhbm73qc30/Simulator-Screenshot-iPhone-15-Pro-2023-12-18-at-12.07.58.jpeg?rlkey=2idlwqs4ug14yo334nahrqity&dl=0

Comment: You would have to calculate the percentage and pass it down. SwiftUI views usually take default alignments of center, leading, trailing or all. For % it has to be calculated. GeometryReader or Layout can both support it.

Comment: There's no reason why a custom `Layout` cannot set proposed sizes on the subviews that are relative to the overall container size in both dimensions. However, exactly how a subview fits itself within the proposed size is down to each individual view. If a subview is given a proposed size that does not correspond to the `sizeThatFits` that it previously reported then the subview might or might not be able to adapt its content to fit the imposed size in a sensible way. If you are having difficulties getting it to work and need more help, please update your post to include a reproducible example.

Comment: Show the code you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for posting the code. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to see the images without logging in to dropbox, please embed the images in the post another time. But by running your code I was able to get the idea.

I would suggest these changes:

1. In `sizeThatFits`, there is no need to compute the sizes of the subviews, because you are always going to use 100% of the width and height that is available. So just return the proposal you are given:

```swift
func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout Void) -> CGSize {
    proposal.replacingUnspecifiedDimensions()
}
```

2. In `frames`, there is no need to ask the subviews for a `sizeThatFits`, because you are always going to give each subview a frame that is a fraction of the width and height. So you can populate the array of frame sizes with the subview sizes you have computed:

```swift
func frames(for subviews: Subviews, in bounds: CGRect) -> [CGRect] {

    // variable definitions as before

    for subview in subviews {
        let subviewHeight = availableHeight * subview.priority / totalPriorities
        let subviewWidth = availableWidth * subview.priority / totalPriorities
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: subviewWidth, height: subviewHeight)
        viewFrames.append(frame)
        y += subviewHeight + spacing
    }

    return viewFrames
}
```

That's it, the function `placeSubviews` is unchanged.

With these changes applied, you can also remove `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` from all the containers. The only places where it is still needed are on the `Text` and on the `Image`, otherwise these do not expand to fill the frame they are given.

This is how it then looks:

[image: Screenshot]